# Swift 3 - Code Update Problems In a Pod

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I updated my project to Swift 3 and I experienced problems in the following pod: https://github.com/Ramotion/expanding-collection and it no longer works :(

The problems are the following, I will explain each problem:

1- "Operator should no longer be declared with body; use a precedence group instead" yellow warning on the following line in the class "Constraints Helper":

```
infix operator >>>- { associativity left precedence 150}
```

How to write this in Swift 3?

2-"'>>>-' produces 'NSLayoutConstraint', not the expected contextual result type 'Void' (aka '()')" red error on the following line in the class "Constraints Helper":

```
func addScaleToFillConstratinsOnView(_ view: UIView) {
        [NSLayoutAttribute.left, .right, .top, .bottom].forEach { attribute in
            (self, view) >>>- { $0.attribute = attribute }
        }
    }
```

How to fix this issue?

3-"Result of operator '>>>-' is unused" yellow warning on the following lines in the AnimatingBarButton class:

```
fileprivate func configureImageView(_ imageView: UIImageView, imageName: String) {
        guard let customView = customView else { return }

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        //    imageView.backgroundColor = .greenColor()

        //    imageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        customView.addSubview(imageView)

//Result of operator '>>>-' is unused - HERE 1
        [(NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, 12), (.centerY, -1)].forEach { info in
            (customView, imageView) >>>- {
                $0.attribute = info.0
                $0.constant = CGFloat(info.1)
            }
        }

//Result of operator '>>>-' is unused - HERE 2
        [NSLayoutAttribute.height, .width].forEach { attribute in
            imageView >>>- {
                $0.attribute = attribute
                $0.constant = 20
            }
        }
    }
```

Also I am getting the same error in this piece of code from the BasePageCollectionCell:

```
fileprivate func createShadowViewOnView(_ view: UIView?) -> UIView? {
        guard let view = view else {return nil}

        let shadow = Init(UIView(frame: .zero)) {
            $0.backgroundColor                           = .clear
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            $0.layer.masksToBounds                       = false;
            $0.layer.shadowColor                         = UIColor.black.cgColor
            $0.layer.shadowRadius                        = 10
            $0.layer.shadowOpacity                       = 0.3
            $0.layer.shadowOffset                        = CGSize(width: 0, height:0)
        }
        contentView.insertSubview(shadow, belowSubview: view)

        for info: (attribute: NSLayoutAttribute, scale: CGFloat)  in [(NSLayoutAttribute.width, 0.8), (NSLayoutAttribute.height, 0.9)] {
            if let frontViewConstraint = view.getConstraint(info.attribute) {
//Result of operator '>>>-' is unused
                shadow >>>- {
                    $0.attribute = info.attribute
                    $0.constant  = frontViewConstraint.constant * info.scale
                }
            }
        }

        for info: (attribute: NSLayoutAttribute, offset: CGFloat)  in [(NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, 0), (NSLayoutAttribute.centerY, 30)] {
//Result of operator '>>>-' is unused
            (contentView, shadow, view) >>>- {
                $0.attribute = info.attribute
                $0.constant  = info.offset
            }
        }

        // size shadow
        let width  = shadow.getConstraint(.width)?.constant
        let height = shadow.getConstraint(.height)?.constant

        shadow.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width!, height: height!), cornerRadius: 0).cgPath

        return shadow
    }





MARK:- PageCollectionView

//Result of operator '>>>-' is unused
collectionView >>>- {
            $0.attribute = .height
            $0.constant  = height
        }
```

How to fix this issue?

I know that this is long, and that the author needs to fix these issues, but the author is not responding or letting us know about an ETA of an update.  And I was just about to finish up my app and then updated to Swift 3, I would really appreciate it if you could guide me through this.  PS: Many people are facing similar issues in this library, I will share your solutions in the support page of that library.

Best,
Aa